# Atom IDE - Python

Tags: python, atom-editor

I know that my question is very basic, but I started learning programming only recently and I've noticed that the *input()* function is not working in the [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(text_editor)) editor by default.

I've tried using the *atom-python-run* package now. Is there another way to make the *input()* function work in Atom?

Comment: In what way is it not working? What did you do? What happened? How can we reproduce the problem?

Comment: It just didn't ask for input in the output terminal. I was trying to use the code "x=input("Enter name: ")" and atom didn't seem to run this code. there were no errors or any kind of response at all. But other simple functions like print are working fine. I was advised to install & use Terminal-Plus package but  It seems Terminal-Plus is no longer maintained. I'm getting the error, Installing “terminal-plus@0.14.5” failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a REPL package instead, most code runners can't accept input.

> A read–eval–print loop (REPL), also termed an interactive toplevel or language shell, is a simple interactive computer programming environment that takes single user inputs, executes them, and returns the result to the user; a program written in a REPL environment is executed piecewise.[1](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=repl)

However, you need to [find](https://atom.io/packages/search?q=repl) one that suits your needs best. Stack Overflow discourages posting suggestions since they're highly subjective.